# Captcha Code Without Using PHP

Tags: .net, server, recaptcha

I've looked through quite a few other questions, but haven't found the answer I'm looking for..

The server I'm using doesn't have PHP (and no I can't put PHP on it) as it's an old webhosting server my office uses, and I'm updating content on an old site.

The issue I'm running into is I made a new contact form, and got it to send through an API (since can't use PHP) but I need a captcha on there, as I'm running into bots sending emails pretty constantly.

How would I go about putting a captcha without using PHP, is there an API to use for that?  I'm so used to using ReCaptcha that I'm practically dependent on it..

Thanks!
Webmasters

Comment: So and what does your server run? Python? ASP.net? Potatoes?

Comment: its philosophical : i want php code without any php code

Comment: If it is a really older server, if linux it likely still has access to perl that can be run as a cgi which is more than enough to setup a simple recaptcha handler. If windows, it likely uses classic asp which would work to do the same. There has to be some sort of scripting handler and really any would do.

Comment: Yeah it's running .net, sorry for not including that.  The only thing about it, is the pages are .html, so would have to include it somehow.

Comment: considering how cheap hosting is, wouldn't just moveing the site to a remote host be easier.

Comment: @Dagon my boss likes to keep things on his own server, and the site in question has really good SEO from being up for as long as it has been, so that's why I'm not creating an entire new site for it (which I recommended first thing).

Comment: moving to a new host will have ZERO SEO effect (ok, as long as you do it right)

Comment: @Dagon like I said, my boss likes to keep things on our server, we don't add new sites to this server, but the site in question has been on it since 2005? or something around that year.  I'm not arguing with you, I think it should be moved or let me put PHP on the server.  But trying to find a work around to keep the boss happy, and get my job done.

Comment: *Captcha Code with .net* google that many examples.

Comment: @Dagon Going to attempt something, will let you know if it works.